# Ruby process to index files on a linux filesystem

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, filesystems

I'm developing a small photo sharing Rails app which will read and display photos from a library of photos on the local filesystem.

In order to avoid scanning the filesystem every time the user loads the page, I want to set up an hourly cron job that indexes all files and stores it in a local MySQL table.

What's the best way to scan the local filesystem and store metadata about local files (e.g. size, file type, modified date, etc..)? Is there a convenient ruby-based library? I'd also like to be able to "watch" the filesystem to know when files have disappeared since the last scan so that they can be deleted from my table.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to look into `inotify`.

https://github.com/nex3/rb-inotify

You can set a `watch` (register a callback in the Linux kernel) on a file or a directory, and everytime something changes in that file/directory, the kernel will notify you immediately with a list of what has changed.

Common events are listed here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify

You will notice that `IN_CREATE` + `IN_DELETE` are the events you are looking for.

**Side note**: `IN_CREATE` only creates the file (it's still empty), you will need to wait until `IN_CLOSE_WRITE` is called, to know data was finished writing to file.